# do i need dinner reservations for the Ahwahnee if i'm staying there?

Tags: california, restaurants, yosemite

Quoting https://www.travelyosemite.com/dining/the-ahwahnee-dining-room/, "*A waitlist is offered to non-hotel guests based upon availability*". If it's offered to non-hotel guests then that would imply that, as a hotel guest, I am not able to get on that waitlist. Does that mean that, as a hotel guest, that I can just go there whenever I please, during their dinner hours (5:30pm - 9:30pm), no reservation required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly go to the Ahwahnee Dining Room when you choose, but you may have to wait.

[This website](https://www.travelyosemite.com/dining/the-ahwahnee-dining-room/) from the Ahwahnee Hotel concessionaire says:

> **Reservations:**
>
> A reservation at the hotel does not automatically include a dining reservation. It is highly encouraged to make dining reservations as soon as possible, before arriving in Yosemite. Please utilize our online reservation system below:
>
> **[RESERVE NOW](https://www.opentable.com/r/the-ahwahnee-hotel-yosemite)**